# Monitor server, process, services, Task scheduler status

Tags: windows, windows-services, monitoring, etl

I am wondering if there is a way to monitor these automatically. Right now, in our production/QA/Dev environments - we have bunch of services running that are critical to the application. We also have automatic ETLs running on windows task scheduler at a set time of the day. Currently, I have to log into each server and see if all the services are running fine or not, or check event logs for any errors, or check task scheduler to see if ETLs ran well etc etc... I have to do all the manually... I am wondering if there is a tool out there that will do the monitoring for me and send emails only in case something needs attention (like ETLs fail to run, or service get stopped for whatever reason or errors in event log etc). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the above information. I looked at the above options but they have a price.. what I did is an inexpensive way to address my concerns..

For my windows task scheduler jobs that run every night - I installed this tool/service from codeplex that is working great.

http://motash.codeplex.com/documentation#CommentsAnchor

For Windows services - I am just setting the "Recovery" Tab in each service "property" with actions to do when it fails. (like restart, reboot, or run a program which could be an email that will notify)

Answer (score 3):

Paessler PRTG Network Monitor can do all that. we have very good experience with it.

http://www.paessler.com/prtg/features

Answer (score 2):

Nagios is the best tool for monitoring. It checks for the server status as well the defined services in it and if any service goes down or system goes down, sends the mail to specified mail id.

Refer the : http://nagios.org/

Answer (score 0):

I built a simple tool (https://cronitor.io) for monitoring periodic/scheduled tasks. The name is a play on "cron" from the unix world, but it is system/task agnostic. All you have to do is make an http request to a unique tracking URL whenever your job runs. If your job doesn't check-in according to the rules you define then it will send you an email/sms message.

It also allows you to track the duration of your jobs by making calls at the beginning and end of your task. This can be really useful for long running jobs since you can be alerted if they start taking too long to run. For example, I once had a backup task that was scheduled every hour. About six months after I set it up it started taking longer than an hour to run!

Answer (score 0):

There is https://eyewitness.io - which is for monitoring server cron tasks, queues and websites. It makes sure each of your cron jobs run when they are supposed to, and alerts you if they failed to be run.